# How do I select more individual files in a uTorrent download that already started?

Tags: utorrent

When I open a single `.torrent` file which contains several files, uTorrent gives me a selection list to choose which files to download.

Say I select 5 out of 10 files, then when that download is complete, I wish to re-open the torrent and select the remaining 5.

Can I do this, and if so, how?

Comment: Why don't you open all the 10 torrents and select a download queue of 5 torrents at a time?

Comment: It's files within one torrent that I select, and a queue of 1 torrent would mean nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Select your completed download
- Go to the "Files" tab in "Detailed Info" (at the bottom) (press <kbd>F5</kbd> if it's not showing)
- Select the files you wish to download (their priority should be 'skip')
- Right-click and set their priority to "Normal"

Answer (score 7):

- Select the torrent.
- Select **Files** tab.
- Right-click the file you want to download.
- Set **Priority** to **Normal**.
- This will deactivate **Don't Download**.

Comment: Funny, in all these years, I've never even noticed that Files tab. I've been concentrating only on the Info tab for ETAs and speeds.